Set up multiple user ssh connections to the same remote host in VS code
I had set up a single connection to a remote host in VS code and everything was working perfectly. I have access to 2 user accounts (dev and engineer) on the same remote host so I tried to set up the 2nd user account also. Unfortunately, this has now broken the initial connection (dev) whereby the VS code server runs from the engineer home directory. As dev does not have access to the engineer home directory I get an error and VS code will not connect.
I would have thought setting up 2 users to the same remote host was straight forward but maybe this is not possible?
My ssh config file looks like this:
Host gch1
  HostName gch1
  User engineer
  IdentityFile C:\Users\MY_MS_USER\.ssh\id_engineer

Host gch1
  HostName gch1
  User dev
  IdentityFile C:\Users\MY_MS_USER\.ssh\id_ed25519

I had tried to change the Host in the config to dev@gch1 and engineer@gch1 but I was prompted for my password for both users in this case.

A workaround would be to start the VS code with one User in the following file. And after establishing first connection, you can start a second VS code connection by changing the "User" field in the following file.
Open a Remote Window -> Configure ssh hosts -> c:\Users\myname\.ssh\config
Host gch1
HostName gch1
User engineer
You should only have one "User" for the given hostname in the above file.

The HOST defines an alias, any choice can be made.
But if you use two times the same alias (two lines with the same HOST ), both blocks will be parsed.
But in the ssh-config each setting can only be set once, the first settings remains in that case.
In your case, the second block can never change anything.
Therefore you need different aliases
Host gch-eng
  User engineer
  IdentityFile C:\Users\MY_MS_USER\.ssh\id_engineer

Host gch-dev
  User dev
  IdentityFile C:\Users\MY_MS_USER\.ssh\id_ed25519

# These settings are used for both
Host gch-*
  HostName gch1
  
  LocalForward 8080 localhost:8080

